# I can't include RelayCommands

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i wanted to include RelayCommands. I wanted to create an assembly to System.Windows.Input to use the ICommands, but the assembly is not available? What is wrong there? I have installed the .net framework Client Profile an Extended? Is it not available at this packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Windows.Input` is in the `PresentationCore` assembly. Just look up the type object explorer and check what assembly it is in. (click the namespace and you'll see the location).

Answer (score 5):

`System.Windows.Input` does not exist as an assembly. `System.Windows.Input` is a namespace in the `PresentationCore` assembly. Also, `RelayCommand` is not a class that's available as part of the .Net framework. You'll either have to build your own or use one provided in an [MVVM](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/) [library](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/).